# Rolling over dataframe pandas and update values if NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use rolling function on my dataframe.
Here my series :

| index | date | id | value_dex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90256 | 2021-05-10 01:45:20 | 101904285 | 7.6 |
| 90257 | 2021-05-10 01:45:20 | 101904285 | 7.6 |
| 90258 | 2021-05-10 02:00:00 | 101904285 | NaN |
| 90260 | 2021-05-10 02:00:44 | 101904285 | 6.9 |
| 90261 | 2021-05-10 02:00:44 | 101904285 | NaN |

What I want :

| index | date | id | value_dex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90256 | 2021-05-10 01:45:20 | 101904285 | 7.6 |
| 90257 | 2021-05-10 01:45:20 | 101904285 | 7.6 |
| 90258 | 2021-05-10 02:00:00 | 101904285 | 7.6 |
| 90260 | 2021-05-10 02:00:44 | 101904285 | 6.9 |
| 90261 | 2021-05-10 02:00:44 | 101904285 | 6.9 |

I would like to drag the values in the column over 30 minutes if NaN. However, I also want the dragging to stop when a new value is encountered on the 30 minute range (in this case, we drag the new value over 30 minutes).

I tried that :

```
ffill = lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.rolling('30T', on='Date')[y].max(),
                                       index=x.index)
        
        data[y] = data.groupby('ID', as_index=False).apply(ffill)
```

But it doesn't work when there is a new value during the rolling. Do you have any solutions in order to resolve my problem ? Maybe an existing function ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can try to use this as a filler for you NaN values:

```
data.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: Hello! It just replace all the NaN values, but not during just 30 minutes